# Pandas get rows after groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Suppose I have the following dataset:

```
uid iid val
 1   1   2
 1   2   3
 1   3   4
 1   4  4.5
 1   5  5.5
 2   1   3
 2   2   3
 2   3   4
 3   4  4.5
 3   5  5.5
```

From this data, I want to first groupby uid, then get last 20% of number of rows from each uid.

That is, since uid=1 has 5 rows, I want to obtain last 1 row (20% of 5) from uid=1.

The following is what I want to do:

```
df.groupby('uid').tail([20% of each uid])
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: what it is your desired output? For instance for uid == 3 ?

Comment: @edyvedy13 Since uid==3 has only 2 rows, 2 * 0.2 = 0.4, my desired output for uid==3 is none. For uid==1, I want the following
uid iid val
1    5    5.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try applying a custom function to `groupby` object. Inside the function calculate how many rows should be taken and take the group's `tail` with that number of rows. `int` rounds toward 0, so any groups with less than 5 rows will not contribute any rows to the result.

```
df.groupby('uid').apply(lambda x: x.tail(int(0.2*x.shape[0])))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use floor division

```
df.groupby('uid').apply(lambda x: x.tail(len(x) // 5))

       uid  iid  val
uid                 
1   4    1    5  5.5
```

You can avoid including the `uid` in the index in the first place by passing `group_keys=False` to the `groupby`

```
df.groupby('uid', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.tail(len(x) // 5))

   uid  iid  val
4    1    5  5.5
```

Comment: How do I drop the first column, which is
uid
1