# Filter rows with any one fulfills conditions in each group with pandas method chaining

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, grouping

For the record, I've read these following threads but none of them seems to fulfill my need:

- [Python pandas - filter rows after groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27488080/python-pandas-filter-rows-after-groupby)
- [Pandas get rows after groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43448895/pandas-get-rows-after-groupby)
- [filter rows after groupby pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41821430/filter-rows-after-groupby-pandas)

Say I have this following table `df`:

```
 user_id  is_manually  created_per_week
----------------------------------------
    10       True             59
    10      False             90
    33       True              0
    33      False             64
    50       True              0
    50      False              0
```

I want to exclude the users who have created nothing, i.e. created_per_week is 0 in both rows of is_manually True and False, which is user 50 in this case.

```
 user_id  is_manually  created_per_week
----------------------------------------
    10       True             59
    10      False             90
    33       True              0
    33      False             64
```

I learned that `df.groupby` doesn't have `query` method and should use `apply` instead.

The closest answer I've got is `df.groupby("user_id").apply(lambda x: x[x["created_per_week"] > 0])`, but it also excludes the row of user 33 manually True, which is undesirable. I've also tried `df.groupby("user_id").apply(lambda x: x[any(x["created_per_week"] > 0)])` but it returns a KeyError.

In other words, I am searching the equivalence of `df %>% group_by(user_id) %>% filter(any(created_per_week > 0))` in R. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply `groupby` then `filter` command to get the output.

```
df.groupby('user_id').filter(lambda x: (x['created_per_week'] != 0).any())

    user_id is_manually created_per_week
0       10        True                59
1       10       False                90
2       33        True                 0
3       33       False                64
```

Comment: So `DataFrameGroupBy.filter` does quite different thing with `DataFrame.filter`... How confusing. Thanks, anyway!

Comment: Yes, `DataFrame.filter` is for selecting column or indexes based on their names. This one is to select rows given a condition. It's confusing.

Answer (score 1):

`transform` + `any`

```
df[df.assign(New=df.created_per_week==0).groupby('user_id').created_per_week.transform('any')]
Out[425]: 
   user_id  is_manually  created_per_week
0       10         True                59
1       10        False                90
2       33         True                 0
3       33        False                64
```

Or simply by using `loc`+`isin`

```
df.loc[df.user_id.isin(df[df.created_per_week!=0].user_id)]
Out[426]: 
   user_id  is_manually  created_per_week
0       10         True                59
1       10        False                90
2       33         True                 0
3       33        False                64
```

From PiR

```
f, u = pd.factorize(df.user_id); df[np.bincount(f, df.created_per_week)[f] > 0]
```

Comment: You can add this `f, u = pd.factorize(df.user_id); df[np.bincount(f, df.created_per_week)[f] > 0]`